# Readonly JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

Supossing that a *JFormattedTextField* is enabled and contains a formatter, is there a way to make it readonly? With a *JTextField*, we just need to suply a custom *Document* and do all the control there, but with a *JFormattedTextField* I suppose that things are a little more complicated as we don't want to mess with its document filter. I really need this feature. So, is there a way to achieve this?

UPDATE: Just my opinion, but it seems that the *JFormattedTextField* is so bad designed in this sense that it leaves no easy solution to this simple problem.

Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField();
// ...
field.setEditable(false);
```

just like for the `JTextField` since `JFormattedTextField` extends `JTextField`

Check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable%28boolean%29) as well.

Comment: I would like it to be focusable at the same time.

Comment: @Marcos one does not prevent the other. You can still focus the textfield and modify the selection using shortcuts such as CTRL+A or SHIFT+ARROWS.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing it now, but it just seems strange because we see no caret cursor when we enter the field. So, for a moment, it gives the sense the the field is not the focus owner.

Comment: @Marcos when a textfield is not editable, its caret is automatically hidden. Yet, nothing prevents you from adding a `FocusListener` and make it visible upon focus gained, and make it invisible upon focus lost: `textfield.getCaret().setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you disable editing by setting isEditable to false?

[textfield.setEditable(false);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable%28boolean%29)

Comment: As I said, I also would like it to be focusable.

Answer (score 1):

What about undoing every change that occurs:

```
JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField("Can't touch this! :)");
formattedTextField.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() {
    @Override
    public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
        e.getEdit().undo();
    }
});
```

Comment: Extra work for no obvious reason. What if one of the undoes fail? Whereas by setting editable to false, you have no way to get exceptions ..

Comment: This one leaves the caret.